# Code Blocks debug with DNDEBEUG defined in compiler settings

Tags: c++

I'm trying to debug my program using `C::B` and added to the compiler settings:

```
 #define 
-DNDEBEUG
```

I get the log:

```
[debug]> run
[debug]No executable specified, use `target exec'.
[debug]Starting program:  
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

Starting the debugger failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'.

[debug]> quit
Debugger finished with status 0
```

anyone can help please?

Comment: Did you consider using GNU `make` with your `Makefile` to compile your code, then use `gdb` on the command line?

Comment: It is either `#define NDEBUG 1` or passing `-DNDEBUG` as a compiler flag

Comment: I'm on windows, how to use this solution?

Comment: You compiler is a command line oriented software (even if your IDE hides that). Study its documentation. Add the appropriate flags to it. BTW, if you are learning programming, I suggest to switch to Linux, it is a very nice environment for programming, and most of the software is free software whose source code you can study and improve

Comment: Actually, the problem comes from -DNDEBUG, desactivating it from the compiler settings and running in debug mode solved my problem
@BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints may not work if the folder you've placed your application has  spaces or other special characters. replacing space with Underscore `_` may solve the issue.

Click [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#In_12.11_or_latest_nightly_builds) for addition details to debug application in Code::blocks